# How to write this kind of a query in mysql5?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, mysql5

I have two tables.

table1

```
    aid   alphabet      Name
    1        A          Apple
    2        A          Air
    3        B          Ball
    4        C          Cat
    5        C          Cow
    6        F          Footbal
    7        G          God
```

table2

```
    did    aid    typeId   groupId   description  
    1       1      3         4        apple description
    2       2      3         4        ffdadfdfd
    3       3      5         6        fdsfsdafasdf
```

I need to select table2 mapping count of each alphabet with a condition typeId 3 and groupId 4.

I wrote this kind of a query but its not fetching all alphabet. Those alphabet have mapping that only its fetching.

`select a.alphabet, count(did) from table1 a left join table2 b on a.aid=b.aid 
where b.typeId=3 and b.groupId=4 group by a.alphabet`

How can I write that kind of a query?

I need this kind of an output.

```
    alphabet   Count
     A          2
     B          0
     C          0
     F          0 .. etc
```

Comment: I guess changing `count(bid)` to `count(b.did) as Count` should fix your query

Comment: sorry I couldn't under stand what you mean.. :(

Comment: @Teneff . by mistake I typed bid.. sorry its not giving proper result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the `typeId` and `groupId` checks in the where clause, you are effectively making your left join into an inner join, by requiring all rows have values in this joined table.  However, this is *not* the case here.  If you move the type and group checks to the `on` clause (in the join), you should get the desired result.

```
select
   a.alphabet,
   count(b.did)
from
   table1 a
   left join table2 b 
      on a.aid=b.aid and b.typeId=3 and b.groupId=4
group by
   a.alphabet
```

Comment: there is no `bid` column in the table description